# How to apply the libraries and plugins configuration loaded in QLibraryInfo in a QApplication?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-libraries

**Context:** I have built a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) executable using *Qt 5.13.1* on an OpenSUSE platform (some Linux distribution).
I have to install it on a platform that already have an old Qt version installed and I can't get rid of it.

So I have installed the proper version of the needed Qt shared libraries (plus the platforms plugins) at a custom location and set up a [*qt.conf*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html) file that will specify the library path to use (same thing for the plugin path).

My own Qt installation folder contains:

- A ***lib/*** directory which contains the libraries to use.
- A ***plugins/*** directory which contains the ***platforms/*** plugin folder.

The *qt.conf* file is installed alongside my executable and is filled as follows:

```
[Paths]
Prefix = relative_path/from/executable_location/to/install_dir/
```

I don't need to specify the ***lib/*** and ***plugins/*** directories in the entries `Libraries` and `Plugins` because they are defaulted at these values.
But even if I set them explicitly, it changes nothing.

I also tried with absolute paths but it changes nothing too.

**Issue:** The issue I encounter is that my executable does not load the libraries, <s>neither find the platforms plugins</s>, despite the *qt.conf* file is successfully loaded.

I have displayed the output of the following instructions:

```
QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PrefixPath);
QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::LibrariesPath);
QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::PluginsPath);
```

And they contains what's I specified in my *qt.conf* file. So the issue does not come from here.

**Question:** I have checked that `QLibraryInfo` field members had been properly initialized but it seems that my `QApplication` instance just ignore it.
How to make the `QLibraryInfo` configuration to be applied by the `QApplication` instance ?

I know that there exist a [`QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#addLibraryPath) member than could be used to load libraries but I can't find anything alike for the Qt plugins as well.
But I'm pretty sure that we don't have to use this function since the information are already loaded by `QLibraryInfo`.

---

**EDIT:**

After some more investigations, I've found that it works fine for loading the plugins.
The problem remains the same for loading the libraries. It seems that I missed something but I cannot figure it out.
For now, I use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable in order to make it work (which is quite ugly).

---

**EDIT 2:**

I found two threads on internet about guys having the same issue:

- https://forum.qt.io/topic/58499/solved-problems-with-setting-paths-to-libs-and-plugins-in-qt-app-s-executable-file
- https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32236-qt-conf-(again)-on-windows

The second one is explaining why the library load does not work.

Actually, **in order to be able to parse the *qt.conf* file, the application needs to have the Core module loaded** (libQt5Core.so.5 in my case) which makes sense (I should have thought of it).

The issue here is that libQt5Core.so.5 is one of the libraries to load (it's a vicious circle), so the executable cannot run at all.

**<s>Solution</s> (still not load any library):** It seems that I can't avoid to either load libQt5Core.so.5 with `LD_PRELOAD` or add it alongside the executable location.

**Note:** We can use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_PRELOAD` if there is no already existing Qt installation in the system "lib" directories.
I use `LD_PRELOAD` here because I want my Qt installation to take precedence over the already existing one (and be loaded first/instead of the system installed ones).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found out what was wrong.

*qt.conf* is parsed by Qt Core at runtime.
But the executable dependencies are loaded before the `QApplication` even exists. If they are not found, the program will just crash right at the beginning (dependencies loading step). And so, *qt.conf* will never be parsed.

In my case, I have an already existing installation of Qt in the system libraries folder. These are the ones that are found by the loader.
In this case, the dependencies are found and the programs runs (assuming there's no incompatibility between the two versions).
But even if the *qt.conf* is now parsed, the good version of the library will still not be loaded because the loader already has loaded the dependencies from the wrong Qt install (found at loading step).

> **Therefore the morality is:** We cannot load executable dependencies by using *qt.conf* because they must be known before execution time (when the loader is looking for them).

**Possible solutions:**

- Install the libraries in one of the folder searched by the loader (*/usr/lib/* for example). If there is an already installed version of the libraries, remove it if possible, or if not, do ensure/check that you placed the proper version in a folder that will be searched first by the loader.
- Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to tell the loader where to search for libraries (if a wrong version is already installed, use `LD_PRELOAD` instead because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will not take precedence over what's inside */etc/ld.so.conf*).
- Set a *rpath* (which locates the proper installation directory of the libraries) when building the executable.
- Add the required shared libraries in the executable directory.
- (Not tested) Explicitly call the loader at application startup with the *--library-path* option (for example: *"$ /lib/ld-linux.so.2 --library-path my_lib_path executable*").

*I may have missed other workarounds, this list is not guaranteed to be exhaustive.*

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your libraries is that the Linux dynamic linker only searches a few standard locations, and other paths configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. One workaround is the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the paths of your libraries. Another is the RPATH/RUNPATH values embedded in your binaries. CMake uses RPATH by default, and you can use QMAKE_RPATH in Qmake projects too. You can assemble by hand a directory with programs and libraries related using  RPATH, but my advice is to [create AppDir / AppImage](https://docs.appimage.org/packaging-guide/) packages using [linuxdeployqt](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt) which is very similar to using the official Qt tools [windeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) and [macdeployqt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-deployment.html).

Comment: I can't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because system installed libraries are loaded first. The solution I used (I forgot to post it here) is to set _rpath_ when building the project from `$$ORIGIN`. This is still inconvenient because I lose the flexibility that should be given by _qt.conf_. But it seems that _qt.conf_ does not work as expected, perhaps it's a bug.

Comment: No, Qt cannot change the way how the Linux linker works. It doesn't work like Windows, you need to live with this.

Comment: You don't understand, I never wanted to change the Linux linker behaviour. qt.conf cannot work because it is parsed by Qt Core. But to be parsed, the executable must be running, so the Qt Core and the dependencies are already loaded at this time (if found, crash if not). This is why qt.conf cannot in any way allow to override the system already existing Qt installation.